# Retrieve entries on custom field date using ElementCriteriaModel

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

I am trying to retrieve an array of entries on a particular section where `inspectionDate` is greater than today's date. Here is the code.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'inspections';
$criteria->inspectionDate > '("now")';
$criteria->order = 'dateCreated asc';
$inspections = $criteria->find();
```

I am getting a `Property "Craft\ElementCriteriaModel.inspectionDate" is not defined.` error when trying to run this code.I have made sure that inspectionDate is the field handle and is also a date type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a syntax error, you did not set the date correctly. This should work

```
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'inspections';
    $criteria->inspectionDate = ">" . time();
    $criteria->order = 'dateCreated asc';
    $inspections = $criteria->find();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Error was because

> $criteria->inspectionDate > '("now")';

This way you can't get today's date.

You could try this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$formattedDate = $date->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME);
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'inspections';
$criteria->inspectionDate = '> '.$formattedDate;
$criteria->order = 'dateCreated asc';
$inspections = $criteria->find();
```

Comment: im marking Robins answer as correct for simplicity sake, your answer works as well.